# How to read data from PTC Windchill Info Engine using Java?

Tags: ptc-windchill

In the project I am assigned to do, it involves reading details of products from Info Engine using a Java Interface. How to do it? Suggest me tutorials or books or anything that helps me get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing `ComponentDataBuilder` and that will return
a well populated `IeTaskInfo` object. It takes the action name as the constructor which gives information of the
task that need to be executed to get the data For example, the following code
snippet demonstrates the use of the “`jca-Search`” task .

```
public class MyDataBuilderWithIETask implements ComponentDataBuilder {
@Override
public Object buildComponentData(ComponentConfig config,
ComponentParams params) throws WTException {
//pass the task name as constructor
IeTaskInfo taskInfo = new IeTaskInfo("jca-Search");
……..
return taskInfo;
}
}
```

For more info please refer

- **Info*Engine User's Guide**
- **Windchill Adapter Guide (Info*Engine)**